# Excel Index Match Sumifs

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumifs

I have a table of data where column headers are account numbers, and I'm trying to sum all data for a specified account when one column (left hand column) equals a certain number.

```
   724| 453 | 345
1  90   0     2
2  91   1     3
3  80   5     4
```

So would like a formula that would sum account 453, or 345 if values in first column are less than 2.  I've written an index/match function to find the column for a specified fund.  But can't seem to add in the sumif or sumifs to help sum.  if there is a better way, please help.

Comment: Can you show us the formula you have so far? Also, currently there are no repeat digits in column `A` of your sample data, will this always be the case? Will column `A` always be sorted as shown?